UDP/TCP application in node js gets stuck until I press Ctrl+C
I have a node js UDP and TCP servers socket application which receives data over these two protocols. I'm using the 'dgram' library for UDP and 'net' library for TCP.
The problem I have is that, once in a while, the application gets stuck and the console does not show any activity... If a enter Ctrl+C, is like the application 'unblocks' and it shows all the console information that seemed to be in a queue to be process. I mean, it's like at some point, the application blocks and all transactions get queued but not processed until I do a Ctrl+C.
I would appreciate any help on how I can debug this issue.
Regards;
Gus

Try to follow here: Nodejs - process hangs on exit (Ctrl+C)
